# double row navigation bar- what's causing it?

Tags: css, search, navigation, margin, padding

[Live site.](http://growingedgecoaching.com)

I think I've been working a little too long on too little sleep to get this site completed. The navigation bar, for some reason I can't seem to find, has resorted to being two levels, regardless of the amount of space I give the links and searchform. Any ideas on what's causing the second row?
Ideally, it should all be one row, with even spacing between the far left link and the right side search form.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it because of the padding:

```
#branding .only-search + #access div {
   padding-right: 205px;
}
```

and the margin:

```
#access div {
    margin: 0 7.6%;
}
```

Reduce both of the padding and margin

Comment: Thank you. I knew it had to have been a combination of elements, just couldn't figure out exactly which.

Answer (score 0):

`padding-right:205px;` in your `style.css` on line `728` is causing this.

Reduce padding accordingly.